# Combinatoric meaning of multinomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$$\binom{n}{k}$$ means how many ways there are to choose $k$ objects from  $n$ total objects.

What is the combinatoric meaning of:

> $$\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, ... , k_n}$$

??

Comment: Multinomials coefficients $${n \choose k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_r}$$ give the number of ways of making partitions of a subset of $n$ elements into $r$ subsets, one of them containing $k_1$ elements, other containing $k_2$ elements and so forth. In fact, one can define a multinomial coefficient as follows
$${n \choose k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_r}={n \choose k_1}\cdot{{n-k_1}\choose k_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot{{n-k_1-k_2-\ldots-k_{r-1}}\choose k_r}$$

Comment: @MarioG: Yes, though I might say *"... $r$ parts, the first containing $k_1$ elements, the second containing $k_2$ elements and so forth."*

Comment: Think of $\binom{n}{k}$ as the number of ways of choosing $k$ objects from a set of $n$ objects and not choosing $n-k$ objects from the same set.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of $\binom{n}{k}$ as the multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k, n-k}$, you can view the binomial coefficient as the number of ways of partitioning $n$ identical objects into two groups one of which contains $k$ objects. This generalizes directly to the multinomial coefficient:
$$\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, ... , k_r}$$
is the number of ways of partitioning $n$ identical objects into $r$ groups, containing $k_1, k_2, \dotsc, k_r$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine having a set of letters that make up a word, e.g. APPLE. How many possibilities exist to create anagrams with these letters?

The trivial answer would be $5!$, as the word APPLE has 5 letters. But this tends to overshoot the real number of possible anagrams, as it contains the same letter twice and we cannot distinguish the two P's from one another. But switching them in the word APPLE would make no difference as they form the same word again.

The multinomial coefficient accounts for these non-distinguishable letters. Let's have a look at the definition:

$$\binom{n}{k_1, k_2, ... , k_r} = \frac{n!}{k_1! \cdot k_2! \cdot ... \cdot k_r!}$$

For every kind of letter (A to Z) we get one term in the denominator. If the letter appears only once, we can omit it, as $1! = 1$. In our case, we have to divide by $2!$ to account for the second instance of the letter P, so we have a total of $\frac{5!}{2!} = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 60$.

If we could distinguish the two instances of P from one another by indexing them, we would have $5!$ combinations to choose from:

$$ A P_1 P_2 L E \neq A P_2 P_1 L E$$